# Group and Sum values on multiple columns

Tags: sql, group-by, sum

I have a table with 8 columns. (The number of possible items are more than 1500. For better reading in this example I name them "item").

| id | project_id | product1 | amount1 | product2 | amount2 | product3 | amount3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | item5 | 22,5 | item2 | 8,5 | item1 | 4,5 |
| 2 | 2 | item4 | 5,5 |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | 1 | item1100 | 55,1 | item1 | 8,5 |  |  |
| 4 | 3 | item8 | 41,2 |  |  |  |  |
| 5 | 2 | item2 | 22,0 | item4 | 8,5 | item2 | 4,5 |

How do I sum all values of exisiting products for a specific project id?

Example: project_id 2

| project_id | product1 | product1_sum | product2 | product2_sum | product3 | product3_sum | product4 | product4_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | item1 | 4,5 | item2 | 35 | item4 | 14 | item5 | 22,5 |

If I have only one product column it's easy but I don't know how to check all 3 of them.

```
SELECT 
  product1, SUM(amount1) AS prod_sum
FROM doe_table
WHERE project_id = 2
GROUP BY product1
```

Comment: Your data model appears flawed, your columns should be rows - then your query is a trivial sum.

Comment: Have one product per row.

Answer (score 1):

- unpivot `productN` and `amountN` columns into rows (depends on db vendor - tag your question with db vendor please),
- group and sum values
- then pivot it back to `productN` and `productN_sum` columns.

Anyway @Stu is right - this is weird data model.

Also note the number of result columns in SQL is fixed in advance. In other words, it is not possible to invoke same SQL command on many datasets and obtain result set with different number of columns for each dataset. Usually some upper bound for number of columns is sufficient, but - as a worst case example - if you have any project with 1500 items you need 3000 columns which is not realistic.